# Help? Schedule and correct exercise question

Tags: exercise, muscle, strength, training, lifting

I’m 18 years old, 122 pounds, and 5’5. I do not want to be muscular I just want to lean out because I am “skinny fat”. I started doing “strength training” 30 minute videos 3 times a week with 10 pound weights but I want to make sure this is an okay routine. I just really don’t want to look bulky or gain too much bulk on my already wide shoulders. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is only to lose weight, you should focus more on your diet.

You say nothing about your routine so there is no way we could assess it's worthiness, 3 times 30 minutes a week seems a bit light, but if your aim is not to build muscles I guess it should do the trick.

That being said, it always amuse me to hear people being afraid of building too much muscles. Building muscles is hard work, you need dedication, a proper diet and a steady overload to gain significant muscle mass. Some people train for years with little to no results because their training or diet are not quite right.

You won't get too bulky because you do a little sport. Relax and enjoy.